# How to show the sum of values as a "Title" for each section in a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

Each section in my table consists of one or more cells that contain a number.  I would like to show the sum of the numbers as part of each section title.

For example:

```
section title: The following sum is: 32
3
5
7
8
9 
section title: The following  sum is: 20 
2
4
6
8
```

My question is, "where do I perform the tally for each section and how do I access just the cells from each section?   i.e. which delegate function, etc...  so that the tally is ready for me to display here in this routine?

Thank you.

Here is my current **TitleForHeaderInSection** delegate function.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];

}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code that pulls each cell's content from the fetchedresultscontroller and places it in the cell.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Grade *sGrade = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    float averageScore, _score, _total;
    _score = [sGrade.scoreValue floatValue];
    _total = [sGrade.scorePossible floatValue];
    averageScore = (_score / _total) * 100;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2.2f%% - (%@ of %@)", averageScore, [sGrade.scoreValue stringValue], [sGrade.scorePossible stringValue]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [sGrade commentInfo];
}
```

So in reality, each of my cells look something like this:    87.00% - (87 / 100).   And so if I have 8 quiz scores like this in the "quizzes" section, then I want to show the average score for all quizzes as part of the title for that section in the grouped UITable.

Comment: I guess you have no need to access the cells. How you are assigning text to each cell?

Comment: I have the user enter a series of test scores, quiz scores, project scores using a data entry UIView.  These data points are saved in entities and are managed as part of a core data managedobject.  I have the fetchedresults sorted by category (quiz, test, etc...)  and I want to show a sum / average for each category as the section header.

Comment: Trying to access the data from the cells directly will not reliably give you the correct answer. UITableView cells are reused, and the number of cells available is equal to the number of cells currently visible in the view. So if you have 100 data points, and the UITableView is only displaying 10 at a time, then you will only be able to access 10 data points.

Comment: Thanks, Sally.  So how does one go about determining a sum/total for all the values that exist per section in a table like this?  I'm using a managedObject model with entities, etc.

Comment: You are getting those data using `sectionInfo.objects` right?

Comment: @Simon - thanks, Simon - i updated the original question and added the code snippet for where I am 'adorning' the cell contents for each cell.  Am I wrong in thinking that I need to 'spin through' the entire table and calculate the sums and averages for each section?  If so, I'm confused as to when/where to do that.  i.e. in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {????}

Comment: Yeah.. Doing the calculations before the tableview loads is a good practice.. You can do that in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:** Method and add a custom view in header with a label in it. The label will display the sum.

I am sure this would work. I have used this in many of my apps.

**Code:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
        UIView *myHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,320,20)];
        myHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        float totpoints = //This would include the summation logic for the section;
        NSString *Sum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",totpoints];

        UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,20)] ;
        myLabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
        myLabel1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        myLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        myLabel1.text = Sum;
        myLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [myHeader addSubview:myLabel1];
        return myHeader;
}
```

I would better go for a dictionary with `section number` as `keys` and `arrays` as `objects` and then simply I have to sum up the array values fetched based on section number.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Also using  `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`  is beneficial because we can put the section header in any position we want as far as right,left and center alignment of the label "myLabel" on the custom View "myHeader" is concerned.

And putting proper background color and other minor but visually important changes can be made using  `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

Comment: whoa - thank you!  I have to run but will try this tonight and comment!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested, but close)

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    float averageScoreTotal, averageScoreCount, _score, _total;
    for (Grade *sGrade in sectionInfo.objects)
    {
        _score = [sGrade.scoreValue floatValue];
        _total = [sGrade.scorePossible floatValue];
        averageScoreTotal += (_score / _total) * 100;
        averageScoreCount++;
    }   

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"The following sum is: %2.2f%%", averageScoreTotal / averageScoreCount];
}
```

Comment: whoa - thank you!  I have to run but will try this tonight and comment!

Comment: the code above worked great for me and is a great answer to my dilema.  I think i will go with the viewForHeaderInSection so as to gain control over appearance.  Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the quickest way:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSNumber *avg=[[sectionInfo objects] valueForKey:@"@avg.scoreValue"];
    NSString *title=[[sectionInfo name] stringByAppendingFormat:@":The following sum is:%@",avg];
    return title;

}
```